# PHP Socket read error

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have three buttons in my html page connected to php script and they send command to another application using socket connection.

1) when the application receiving the command and the xampp server runs on localhost it works fine, but when i try to send the command on a network it sometimes it works and sometimes it does not.

2) what can be the reason behind this.

**code for button1**

```
<?php
// Fill up array with names
$q=$_GET["q"];



$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$host = $_GET["vz"];
$port=6100;
$buffer=$q ."\0";
$len= strlen($buffer);

socket_connect($sock, $host, $port);
socket_sendto($sock, $buffer, $len, 0 , $host, $port);


$buffer='COMMAND HERE';
$len= strlen($buffer);


socket_sendto($sock, $buffer, $len, 0 , $host, $port);

echo( socket_read($sock, 65535) );

socket_close($sock);


?>
```

**code for button 2**

```
?php


$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$host = $_GET["x"];
$port=6100;
$buffer='COMMAND HERE';

$len= strlen($buffer);

socket_connect($sock, $host, $port);
socket_sendto($sock, $buffer, $len, 0 , $host, $port);



$len= strlen($buffer);


socket_sendto($sock, $buffer, $len, 0 , $host, $port);

echo( socket_read($sock, 65535) );

socket_close($sock);


?>
```

**code for button 3**

```
<?php


$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$host = $_GET["x"];
$port=6100;
$buffer='COMMAND HERE';

$len= strlen($buffer);

socket_connect($sock, $host, $port);
socket_sendto($sock, $buffer, $len, 0 , $host, $port);



$len= strlen($buffer);


socket_sendto($sock, $buffer, $len, 0 , $host, $port);

echo( socket_read($sock, 65535) );

socket_close($sock);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for errors with this code, might be a timeout ?

```
if ($socket === false) {
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked fine with chrome and the latest version of internet explorer

Comment: I mean to say that the same code i had pasted worked fine when IE was chaged to the latest version